# Migrating to 2.6: lang is not being implicitly propagated out of the request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have a simplified version of a Controller that looks like this (see the full file [here](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/troubleshooting/app/controllers/Application.scala)):

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (implicit
                             indexView: views.html.index,
                             deadbolt: DeadboltActions,
                             userService: UserService) extends InjectedController with I18nSupport {
  import scala.concurrent._

  def index =
    TryCookieAuthAction { implicit jContext =>
      deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()() { implicit request =>
        Future {
          implicit val lang = request.acceptLanguages.head
          Ok(indexView(userService))
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that if I comment the explicit extraction of `lang` then the view won't see it. Why is that? It used to work before Play 2.6 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Messages`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaI18N#Using-Messages-and-MessagesProvider) docs state that

> ...you can wrap a given `Lang` together with the `MessagesApi` to
>   create a `play.api.i18n.Messages` instance.

so consider refactoring views to take

```
implicit messages: Messages
```

instead of

```
implicit messagesApi: MessagesApi, lang: Lang
```

This way we do not have to explicitly handle `Lang`, because [`I18nSupport.request2messages`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.I18nSupport@request2Messages(implicitrequest:play.api.mvc.RequestHeader):play.api.i18n.Messages) implicit conversion will take care of that under the hood.

For example, say we have the following `view/index.scala.html`

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages)

@messages("salutation")
```

and and the following English externalised messages `conf/messages.en`

```
salutation=live long and prosper
```

and the following Italian externalised messages `conf/messages.it`

```
salutation=vivi a lungo ed in prosperita
```

and the following allowed languages `conf/application.conf`

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "it" ]
```

then the controller does not need to explicitly handle `Lang` as long as we extend `I18nSupport` and have an implicit request in scope like so

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) 
    extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```

Now HTTP request with `Accept-Language: it` header should respond with

```
vivi a lungo ed in prosperita
```

whilst one with `Accept-Language: en` with

```
live long and prosper
```

Also consider [I18N API Migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/MessagesMigration26).